# Can I pass some props to root.tsx in my Qwik application?

Tags: qwik

I'm using express to run my Qwik app. In `entry.express.tsx` file we have this line:

```
const { router, notFound } = createQwikCity({ render, qwikCityPlan, manifest });
```

And `render` is imported this way:

```
import render from "./entry.ssr";
```

In `entry.ssr.tsx` file we have this code:

```
import {
    renderToStream,
    type RenderToStreamOptions,
} from "@builder.io/qwik/server";
import { manifest } from "@qwik-client-manifest";
import Root from "./root";

export default function (opts: RenderToStreamOptions) {
    const props = {
        name: "somebody"
    }
    return renderToStream(<Root {...props} />, {
        manifest,
        ...opts,
        // Use container attributes to set attributes on the html tag.
        containerAttributes: {
            lang: opts.serverData?.locale || "en",
            ...opts.containerAttributes,
        },
    });
}
```

So, `<Root />` is in fact the root component exported in the `root.jsx` file. So, I decided to pass `{ name: "somebody" }` to the `root.tsx` file and log it:

```
export default component$(props => {
    console.log(props)
```

But it does not print anything.

I need to read something from the disk when my Qwik app gets loaded, and pass it to my app. Is that possible?